# How to set height of custom soft keyboard in android?

Tags: android, height, android-softkeyboard

I want to create a soft keyboard which needs to be displayed in only half of the device screen.

The main intention is that user can see and select items in the screen even while the keyboard is displayed (as it will not be in full screen).

I tried changing the layout height parameter in "inputView" and "candidateView" xml. But, the whole keyboard height is not getting changed.
Please propose a way to achieve this.

input.xml

```
 <com.example.android.softkeyboard.LatinKeyboardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="5px"
    android:layout_height="5px"
    />
```

qwerty.xml

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:horizontalGap="0px"
android:verticalGap="0px"
android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height"
android:paddingTop="80px"
android:layout_height="50px"
android:layout_width="50px"
>
```

-Thanks in advance.